# Creating new vector which is "inverse" of existing vector (e.g. water surrounding island) in QGIS

Tags: qgis, vector, water

I want to create a new vector layer which represents the surrounding water of a particular island I am working with in QGIS. Is it possible to create a water shape based on an "inverted selection" or the empty areas of an existing vector layer?

As @jdavid05 mentions, I do need to create another vector. The question is still a duplicate, though, as I think the following method here applies: [Create a new vector layer that fills space between other polygons in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/49489/create-a-new-vector-layer-that-fills-space-between-other-polygons-in-qgis)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the symbology "inverted polygons"

[image]
[image]
[image]

And you can also style your inverted polygon

[image]
[image]

Comment: This is what immediately came to mind when I saw this question as well. This doesn't make a new shapefile though which jserv might need.

Comment: In this case @jdavid05 is correct. I would like to create a water shape, not just to colour the inverted polygons as this answer seems to suggest. Is it possible to reopen this question?

Comment: @jserv In this case, has you try the answer in the link?